# Traverse results in TreeTable binding - SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5, treetable

I have an XML view with `TreeTable`. The binding is with an oData which returns something like `results-->` then in every result something called as "ABC" which is in itself an array.

In my table I want to display the `results-->` fields for parent and for the row ( which does not have child). For the child rows, need to display, `results--> ABC --`> then the property binding. But, the way I did coding, it works fine for rows that have children (parent and child binding is fine) but for rows without children also some controls are being made visible. I am not sure how to set visible syntax.

**XML View**:

```
<table:TreeTable rows="{path:'List>/results', parameters:{arrayNames:['ABC']}}"  >
        <table:Column id="t1" width="200px">                                
          <Label text="Column1"/>
          <table:template>
            <HBox>    
              //want to make visible only for parent and the row which does not have child    
              <Text text="{path: 'List>', formatter: '.formatCoumn1'}"  visible="{= !${List>?????}}"/>              
              //want to make visible only for child row     
              <DatePicker value="{List>ExpiryDate}" visible="{List>?????}"/>                                            
             </HBox>
         </table:template>
        </table:Column>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Text text="{path: 'List>ABC'}"  visible="{= ${List>switch} !== undefined}"/>
<DatePicker value="{List>ExpiryDate}" visible="{= ${List>switch} === undefined}" />
```

The [Expression Binding](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0) in the Demo Kit has some additional examples, that might work for you:

```
enabled="{= ${/orderStatus} !== null }"
enabled="{= ${/items}.length > 0 }"
```